# In Angularjs UI-Router, how to check URL with conditions?

Tags: regex, url, numbers, integer

Now I have this piece of code in my route file.

```
$stateProvider.
state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/home.client.view.html'
}).
state('thread', {
    url: '/:thread_id',
    templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/thread.client.view.html'
}).
state('privacy', {
    url: '/privacy',
    templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/privacy.client.view.html'
}).
state('terms', {
    url: '/privacy',
    templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/terms.client.view.html'
});
```

My goal is: when thread_id is a pure integer, it navigates to thread.client.view.html. Otherwise, it navigates to other pages like privacy, terms etc.

Is that possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it.

```
state('thread', {
    url: '/{thread_id:[0-9]{0,100}}',
    templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/thread.client.view.html'
}).
```

Reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing Regex Parameters.